# Convert Year Hour Date Interval to Number of Days

Tags: mysql, date, mysql-5.1

I have an interval of 0012-11-03 (year-month-day) and would like to convert it to number of days:

12 * ~365 + Num of days From 01-01 To 11-03 = answer.

Leap year must be accounted for. (answer + 12/4 ??)

The closest thing I could come up with is using TO_DAYS() MySQL 5.1 but that function "does not take into account the days that were lost when the calendar was changed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really working with dates of 0012-11-03?  I.e. the year 12 AD?

The calendar was not changed recently.  They're referring to the days lost in the conversion from the Julian calendar to the Gregorian calendar in 1582 AD.

This should work:

```
SELECT TO_DAYS('2012-11-03') - TO_DAYS('2012-01-01');
```

Returns 307.

Comment: The interval was a return of some math, your post gave me an idea to redo that calculation to show the days difference without needing to convert the resulting interval to days.